# Internal Salesforce Error (GACK) Deleting Account w/ restrictedDelete ContentVersion

Tags: apex, exception, gack

I recently 'succeeded' in getting an `Internal Salesforce Error` aka GACK. Per [Josh Kaplan's blog page](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html), I am posting the details and cause in case someone else runs into this before SFDC fixes it. And yes, it took hours to figure this out.

**Environment: Sandbox cs21, Unlimited Edition**
Schema

```
                 Account
    -----------------------------------
     |                           |
    Case                   ContentVersion
```

both relationships are defined as `restrictedDelete` - meaning, you can't delete the parent before deleting the child. The `Account->Cases` relationship comes that way OOB, the `Account -> ContentVersion` relationship you have to declare that way in the metadata.

**Test Class, same results V35, V36**

```
@isTest
private class FooTest {
  @isTest
  private static void testGackContentVersion() {
    // create two Accounts
    Account[] aList = new List<Account>{new Account(name = '00gack'), 
                                        new Account(name='01gack')};
    insert aList;

    // Create a ContentVersion (restrictedDelete on Account->CV relationship is true)
    ContentVersion[] cvList = new List<ContentVersion> {
                                      new ContentVersion(title='00_0gack_2020_12_31',                                     
                                                         account__c=aList[0].id,                                                                     
                                                         versiondata =Blob.valueOf('fooBody'),
                                                         pathOnClient='c:\foo.pdf',
                                                         language='en_US')};
    insert cvList;
    delete aList;  // gack occurs here?  
  } 

  @isTest
    private static void testGackCase() {
    // create two Accounts
    Account[] aList = new List<Account>{new Account(name = '00gack'),
                                        new Account(name='01gack')};
    insert aList;

    // Create a Case (restrictedDelete on Account->Cases relationship =true)
    Case[] csList = new List<Case> {new Case(accountId = aList[0].id,subject='00_0gack')};
    insert csList;
    delete aList;  // gack occurs here?  
  } 

}
```

**For the deletion of the Account with child ContentVersion (1st testmethod)**

```
Internal Salesforce Error: 1276196940-33783 (-502955608) (-502955608)
```

**For the deletion of the Account with child Case (2nd testmethod)**

```
System.DmlException: Delete failed. First exception on row 0 with id 001q000000QIpshAAD; 
first error: DELETE_FAILED, Your attempt to delete 00gack could not be completed because it is associated 
with the following cases.: C-00004813: []
```

Comment: Please post only query part in the question and answer in the answered section. Thanks for sharing info...

Comment: sorry @MohithShrivastava - I thought I needed to wait 24 hours to answer my own question. Chagrined. Edits done

Comment: Did you create a case with salesforce support for the gack? That would help get it fixed.

Comment: @CarolynGrabill - yes I did, see meta post here: http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/2084/why-doesnt-salesforce-thank-you-if-you-discover-a-reproducible-internal-salesfo?cb=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DIAGNOSIS**

The correct and I suspect intended behavior is to generate the message

```
...Your attempt to delete someName could not be completed because it is associated 
with the following someSobjects ...
```

for all child SObjects defined in the metadata `Schema.ChildRelationship` with `isRestrictedDelete=true`. But, for some reason, the `ContentVersion` child doesn't play nicely.

This can cause havoc with any delete logic you might have that deletes a parent of `ContentVersion`, expecting any exception in the delete to be thrown and hence, catchable. Note that in the UI, the Internal Salesforce Error does not occur and, I think, if the `ContentVersion` was created via the UI, the same above logic run in Execute Anonymous Apex also throws a normal exception.

**WORKAROUND**

If using code to delete parents of a `restrictedDelete` child `ContentVersion` and you are expecting an exception to be thrown and caught, think again. You'll need to explicitly delete the `ContentVersion` (by deleting the associated `ContentDocument`) before deleting the `ContentVersion's` parent.

Comment: Thank you and no sorry please :)..Thanks again for sharing what you learned with community